# Too many corrupted file while installing Cygwin on Windows

Tags: windows, cygwin

I'm installing from internet Cygwin 2.897 on my Windows PC. At some point there are too many pop-up windows saying:

"Unable to extract blabla -- corrupted package?"
or
"Unable to extract blabla. The file is in use or some other error occurred."

I can go on pressing the "Continue" button but there are too many pop-ups that it is almost impossible to proceed.

Looking on internet it seems I'm the only one facing this problem. What happened? How can I fix it?

Comment: check your AV, maybe it is interfering with the download

Answer (score 0):

I had errors like this and it turned out I was out of memory on a hard disk.

Do you have some disk space left? For me freeing some helped.